# Binary image display in Django template

Tags: python, html, django-templates, base64

**pyShelf Open Source eBook Server**

I am attempting to display a database stored binary image in my django template. I have created a custom filter to return the image b64encoded, and have also tried just using it as is in the database.

A in depth explanation is available on my GitHub issue @ [Binary image display in template #12](https://github.com/th3r00t/pyShelf/issues/12) along with code examples.

**Template**

```
{% for book in Books %}
    <li>{{ book.title }} <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image;base64,{{ book.cover | bin_2_img }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/> </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**bin_2_img**

```
from base64 import b64encode
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def bin_2_img(_bin):
    if _bin is not None: return b64encode(_bin)
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image;base64,b'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'" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
```

*note the binary has been reduced in size for this posting to stay under the character limit*

**DB Stored Images**
*One should endeavor not to store images in a database, instead storing a path*

> Of this I am very aware, however for the time being the images are ideally originally stored in side each epubs file. Epub files are semi-analogous to zip files. In order to minimize repeatedly opening and querying the file each time the image is needed I chose to store it instead.

Future releases will most likely be changed to extract the image prior to storing the book and renaming it to match the book title, or file name then storing it in the directory of the book, and a link to the new file in the db instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

b64encode returns bytes type in python3.  You need to convert it to string type to prevent outputting the b prefix in the template.

```
@register.filter
def bin_2_img(_bin):
    if _bin is not None: return b64encode(_bin).decode('utf-8')
```